# Loading ublock with custom filter in Chromium Selenium and Python3

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, google-chrome-extension

I'm developing a scraping script to collect some data which is behind an authwall, I've got a custom filter in ublock which gets me past the authwall however when i load chromium with ublock using Selenium it doesn't have the filters. I'm using Linux if that helps.

I've tried getting it to pause before getting the information to allow me to check the filters in place and it is blank.

Here is a portion of the code

```
    from selenium import webdriver
    from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options


    chrome_option_settings = Options()
    chrome_option_settings.add_argument('--window-size=1920x1080')
    extension_path = r'/home/user/.config/chromium/Default/Extensions/cjpalhdlnbpafiamejdnhcphjbkeiagm/1.20.0_0'
    chrome_option_settings.add_argument('load-extension='+extension_path)


    chrome_driver = "/usr/bin/chromedriver"
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_option_settings, executable_path=chrome_driver)
    driver.get(url)
```

I've also tried to load the Chrome profile using either however neither help.

```
    chrome_options.add_argument("user-data-dir=/home/user/.config/chromium/Default")
```

or

```
    chrome_options.add_argument("--profile-directory=/home/user/.config/chromium/Default")
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Having similar issue were you able to solve :)?

Answer (score 0):

You could try using Options() and invoking add_extension with the path to ublock, hope this helps

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

chrome_options = Options()
executable_path = "path_to_webdriver"
extension_path = r'/home/user/.config/chromium/Default/Extensions/cjpalhdlnbpafiamejdnhcphjbkeiagm/1.20.0_0'

chrome_options.add_extension(extension_path)

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=executable_path, chrome_options=chrome_options)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, the extension is currently loading however the settings are all default and don't contain the filters I have added for some reason. Also I should mention: I can't find the .crx file for the life of me however calling     chrome_option_settings.add_argument('load-extension='+extension_path) pointing to the extension directory works.

Comment: @PaulClarke Sorry I couldn't be of anymore help buddy, bit of a strange one there

Comment: having the same issue currently.. I'd like to load ublock with predefined settings. I can set it no-porblem on Windows manually, but on Linux I don;t even have a display and the GUI :D